# My app does not receive Parse push notifications

Tags: android, parse-platform, push-notification

I have setup my app for Parse notifications and strictly followed the instructions, but somehow I don't receive any notification. What is the problem here?

**Update: I just tried sending a test push notification on the Parse.com website. That should work without subscribing to a channel (see comment)**

My AndroidManifest.xml (only the relevant parts):

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />

    <permission android:protectionLevel="signature"
        android:name="co.bla.bla.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="co.bla.bla.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />

<!-- Push notification setup -->
        <service android:name="com.parse.PushService" />
        <receiver android:name="co.bla.bla.ParsePushReceiver"
            android:exported="false">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.RECEIVE" />
                <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.DELETE" />
                <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.OPEN" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <receiver android:name="com.parse.GcmBroadcastReceiver"
            android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />

                <category android:name="co.bla.bla" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

    </application>
```

And I have extended `ParsePushBroadcastReceiver`:

```
public class ParsePushReceiver extends com.parse.ParsePushBroadcastReceiver{

    @Override
    protected void onPushReceive(Context context, Intent intent ) {

        ParseAnalytics.trackAppOpenedInBackground(intent);

        String s = intent.getStringExtra("alert");
        Log.d("Push received", s);
        // do your stuff here
        if(SugarSnapApplication.INACTIVE)
            super.onPushReceive(context, intent);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPushOpen(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Intent i = new Intent(context, SugarActivity.class);
        i.putExtras(intent.getExtras());
        i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        context.startActivity(i);
    }

    @Override
    protected Notification getNotification(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return super.getNotification(context, intent);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPushDismiss(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPushDismiss(context, intent);
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you subscribe to the channel you are sending?

Comment: @IliiazAkhmedov I just tried sending test push notifications on Parse.com website.

Comment: I mean in the application class in your app did you call ParsePush.subscribeInBackground("<your default main channel name>");

Comment: @IliiazAkhmedov No, I did not call that in my Application class. Is that really necessary when I send to "Everyone" through the website? And what would the name of that channel be if it's necessary? BTW, I don't see anywhere in the setup instructions that that's necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found out what the problem was. I have renamed the whole package name of my application a couple of days ago and apparently the change was not made everywhere and the applicationId in my `build.gradle` file was still the old one. So naturally the package name in my AndroidManifest.xml was not the same as the one saved in my `Installation` class.